# A problem occurred during the parallel computing in matrix in golang

Tags: parallel-processing, channel

I came across a bug when I try to add a fixed value to each element of the matrix in my toy example. My thought was to separate the whole matrix into several sub-matrix and use a map to hold the start index and the submatrix during parallel calculation. I already finished that previous requirement. But when I would like to step further, I would like to let my borders interact with each other, and not lose any useful information at the same time, like the cellular automata games, their position would be determined by some neighbors. Therefore, rather than separate the whole matrix into a perfect way, I purposely add some redundant rows to allow the borders to obtain the correct value, like the following way, and in the final combination part, I could simply leave those incorrect borders and retain the correct calculated body.

[image]

Suppose we have three CPUs, and the input matrix is a 10 by 10 matrix. I therefore would create three go routines. As previously suggested, I allow some rooms to handle the border situation. I, therefore, made some room, or overlap between different sub-board during the segmentation. To achieve the purpose, I manually add one row before the sub-board and one row after the sub-board, which means I have to write three if statements, the first situation is the sub-board started with 0, we could only add one row from the next sub-board. The second situation would be the middle one, add one row before at the top and one-row bottom from below. The last situation would be not to add another row from below. However, when I try to run the code in parallel, it seems that some pollution occurred during the goroutine and I had no idea how would that happen. Supposedly, the input sub-board before the goroutine and the sub-board in the go-routine should be the same one, although the order might differ. In this case, the value in the goroutine function might be polluted. I had no idea why this situation might occur. Since the print method and breakpoint method may not work in parallel programming. I am really confused and have no ideas what's going on in this case. I also attached the code below, if you would like to replicate it.

```
func TestParallelMatrixMapInteraction(t *testing.T) {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    boards := GenerateMatrix(10)
    //for i := 0; i < len(boards); i++ {
    // fmt.Println(boards[i])
    //}
    numProcess := 3
    nRows := len(boards)

    subRows := nRows / numProcess
    sumRow := func(subBoard [][]int, c chan map[int][][]int, startIdx int) {
        // input
        fmt.Println("The input of subBoard in goroutine: ", subBoard, "with start idx ",startIdx)
        defer wg.Done()
        for i := 0; i < len(subBoard); i++ {
            for j := 0; j < len(subBoard[i]); j++ {
                subBoard[i][j] += 4
                //fmt.Println(subBoard[i][j])
            }
        }
        subBoardMap := make(map[int][][]int)
        subBoardMap[startIdx] = subBoard
        //fmt.Println("After the modification, the subBoard is:", subBoardMap)
        c <- subBoardMap
    }

    c := make(chan map[int][][]int)
    //c := make(chan map[int][][]int, subRows)

    // iterate through all the available number of process
    for i := 0; i < numProcess; i++ {
        // split into numProcess approx . equal pieces
        startIdx := i * subRows
        endIdx := (i + 1) * subRows
        if startIdx ==0  {
            wg.Add(1)
            subBoard := boards[startIdx : endIdx+1]
            fmt.Println("The input of subBoard: ", subBoard, "with start idx ",startIdx)
            go sumRow(subBoard, c, startIdx)
        } else if i < numProcess-1 {
            wg.Add(1)
            subBoard := boards[startIdx-1 : endIdx+1]
            fmt.Println("The input of subBoard: ", subBoard, "with start idx ",startIdx-1)
            go sumRow(subBoard, c, startIdx-1)
        } else { // i = numProcess -1
            wg.Add(1)
            subBoard := boards[startIdx-1:]
            fmt.Println("The input of subBoard: ", subBoard, "with start idx ",startIdx-1)
            go sumRow(subBoard, c, startIdx-1)
        }
    }

    newBoard := GenerateEmptyMatrix(10)

    for i := 0; i < numProcess; i++ {
        subBoardMap := <-c
        //fmt.Println("=====================================")
        //fmt.Println("The output from channel: It would be a map",subBoardMap)
        var startIdx int
        var subBoard [][]int
        for idx, value := range subBoardMap {
            startIdx = idx
            subBoard = value
        }
        endIdx := startIdx + len(subBoard)

        var actualStart int
        var actualEnd int
        if startIdx == 0 {
            actualStart = startIdx
            actualEnd = actualEnd - 1
        } else if endIdx == len(newBoard) {
            actualStart = startIdx + 1
            actualEnd = endIdx
        } else {
            actualStart = startIdx + 1
            actualEnd = endIdx - 1
        }

        for j := actualStart; j < actualEnd; j++ {
            newBoard[j] = subBoard[j-actualStart]
        }
    }
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("=================ready to draw the matrix====================")

    for i := 0; i < len(newBoard); i++ {
        fmt.Println(newBoard[i])
    }

}

func GenerateMatrix(size int) [][]int {
    board := make([][]int, size)
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        board[i] = make([]int, size)
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(board); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(board[0]); j++ {
            board[i][j] = i
        }
    }
    return board
}

func GenerateEmptyMatrix(size int) [][]int {
    board := make([][]int, size)
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        board[i] = make([]int, size)
    }
    return board
}
```

I also attached the previous mentioned correctly run matrix samples and I am really curious about what cause that difference and where actually my bug is.

```
func TestParallelMatrixMap(t *testing.T) {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    boards := GenerateMatrix(20)
    for i := 0; i < len(boards); i++ {
        fmt.Println(boards[i])
    }
    numProcess := 3
    nRows := len(boards)

    subRows := nRows / numProcess
    sumRow := func(subBoard [][]int, c chan map[int][][]int, startIdx int) {
        fmt.Println("The input of subBoard in goroutine: ", subBoard, "with start idx ",startIdx)
        defer wg.Done()
        for i := 0; i < len(subBoard); i++ {
            for j := 0; j < len(subBoard[0]); j++ {
                subBoard[i][j] += 4
            }
        }
        subBoardMap := make(map[int][][]int)
        subBoardMap[startIdx] = subBoard
        c <- subBoardMap
    }

    c := make(chan map[int][][]int, subRows)

    // iterate through all the available number of process
    for i := 0; i < numProcess; i++ {
        // split into numProcess approx . equal pieces
        startIdx := i * subRows
        endIdx := (i + 1) * subRows
        if i < numProcess-1 {
            wg.Add(1)
            go sumRow(boards[startIdx:endIdx], c, startIdx)
        } else { // i = numProcess -1
            wg.Add(1)
            go sumRow(boards[startIdx:], c, startIdx)
        }
    }

    newBoard := GenerateEmptyMatrix(20)

    for i := 0; i < numProcess; i++ {
        subBoardMap := <-c
        var startIdx int
        var subBoard [][]int
        for idx, value := range subBoardMap {
            startIdx = idx
            subBoard = value
        }
        endIdx := startIdx + len(subBoard)

        for j := startIdx; j < endIdx; j++ {
            newBoard[j] = subBoard[j-startIdx]
        }
    }
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("=================ready to draw the matrix====================")

    for i := 0; i < len(newBoard); i++ {
        fmt.Println(newBoard[i])
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself, it normally would be a shallow copy and deep copy problem in the slice of golang. Because I used [startIdx-1:endIdx+1] method to add two adjacent lines, and owing to the inner nature of disorder during parallel computing in goroutine, the previous lines may have been modified, which accounts for the situation that my output would be a mess and without order.

To avoid this problem, you could create a copy function which create a new slice and iterate through the old one and assign the value to the new one. Only in this way, the slice we obtained would be a deep copy and independent with other modifications.